# Horizontal scrolling with cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport inside NgbModal

Tags: angular-material2, horizontal-scrolling, angular-bootstrap

I'm displaying this component in an NgbModal:

```
<div id="gallerypopup">
  <div id="main-image">
    <lib-ngx-image-zoom id="zoomer"
      [thumbImage]="item.thumbnailUrls[selectedIndex]"
      [fullImage]="item.imageUrls[selectedIndex]"
      zoomMode="click"
      ></lib-ngx-image-zoom>
  </div>
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport orientation="horizontal" itemSize="400" minBufferPx="400" maxBufferPx="400" class="viewport">
    <span *cdkVirtualFor="let thumbnail of item.thumbnailUrls; let index = index;" class="thumbcell">
      <img [src]="thumbnail" height="300" (click)="selectImage(index)" /
    </span>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
#gallerypopup {
  height: 75%;
  width: 75%;
}

.thumbcell {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.viewport {
  height: 300px;
}

.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.ngxImageZoomFullContainer {
  cursor: zoom-out;
}

.ngxImageZoomThumbnail {
  cursor: zoom-in;
}
```

But even though the scrolling viewport is set to horizontal orientation, the thumbnails still appear stacked vertically. How do I fix this? I suspect the problem is that the scrollable area is being incorrectly constrained to fit its width inside the width of the modal popup (which for some reason isn't 75% of the browser window, despite the first CSS rule).

Answer (score 3):

Thing is .viewport children layout is still vertical.

Solution :

```
.viewport .cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

here is [stackblatz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-horizontal-virtual-scroll?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-virtual-scroll-horizontal-example.css)  this is example from [angular material doc](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview#viewport-orientation) and i have modified it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried the following in order to display the elements horizontally?

```
.cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper .viewport {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```